# Uncaught Error: n.onSuccess is not a function AWS Cognito

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I'm getting the following javascript error when I try to set up an authenticated user with a new password and I can't figure out where it's happening. Once I call my register function, the user is actually able to overwrite their temp password with a new one and everything looks fine in the cognito console. They're also able to login with their new password.

```
Uncaught Error: n.onSuccess is not a function      request.js?1405:31
  at Response.eval (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:1290), <anonymous>:17:14072)
  at Request.eval (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:1746), <anonymous>:355:18)
  at Request.callListeners (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:1056), <anonymous>:105:20)
  at Request.emit (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:1056), <anonymous>:77:10)
  at Request.emit (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:1746), <anonymous>:668:14)
  at Request.transition (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:1746), <anonymous>:22:10)
  at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:1884), <anonymous>:14:12)
  at eval (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:1884), <anonymous>:26:10)
  at Request.eval (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:1746), <anonymous>:38:9)
  at Request.eval (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:1746), <anonymous>:670:12)
```

My register function:

```
import {Config, CognitoIdentityCredentials} from 'aws-sdk'
import {CognitoUserPool, CognitoUser, AuthenticationDetails, CognitoUserAttribute} from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js'

import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode'
import store from './store'

export default class CognitoAuth {

  register (username, email, pass, newPassword, cb) {
    let authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails({
      Username: username,
      Password: pass
    })
    let cognitoUser = new CognitoUser({
      Username: username,
      Pool: this.userPool
    })

    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
      newPasswordRequired: (userAttributes, requiredAttributes) => {

        // the api doesn't accept this field back
        delete userAttributes.email_verified

        cognitoUser.completeNewPasswordChallenge(newPassword, userAttributes, this)
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Register.vue

```
signup () {
  this.$cognitoAuth.register(this.username, this.email, this.oldPass, this.newPass, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      this.error = true
      this.errMsg = err.message
      console.error(err)
    } else {
      console.log('Login Successful:', result)
      this.$router.replace(this.$route.query.redirect || '/search')
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the `onSuccess` callback implementation, which is called on success with the a new session. See line 341 in [CognitoUser.js](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js/blob/master/src/CognitoUser.js).

For example:

```
.
.
.
cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
    onSuccess: (result) => {
        // User authentication was successful.
    },

    onFailure: (err) => {
        // User authentication was not successful.
    },

    mfaRequired: (codeDeliveryDetails) => {
        // MFA is required to complete user authentication.
        // Get the code from user and call:
        cognitoUser.sendMFACode(mfaCode, this)
    },

    newPasswordRequired: (userAttributes, requiredAttributes) => {

        // the api doesn't accept this field back
        delete userAttributes.email_verified;

        cognitoUser.completeNewPasswordChallenge(newPassword, userAttributes, this);
    }
})
.
.
.
```